# Phalcon php undefined variable session

Tags: php, session, undefined, phalcon

I am studying Phalcon and I'm trying to set username to session OOP Phalcon style. Here is what I have in my controller:

```
$users = Users::find(array($conditions, 'bind' => $parameters));
            if (count($users) > 0) {
                //login
                $this->session->start();
                $this->session->set("username", $username);
                $this->view->successMessage = "You are logged in";

            }
```

This is a chunk of loginAction. If I print_r($_SESSION); in login.volt (where user gets redirected after login action) it prints out the session, but in other views when I try to print session I get an error: undefined variable session.
In my services.php I have

```
$di->setShared('session', function() {
    $session = new Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files();
    $session->start();
    return $session;
});
```

Would be grateful for any help

**EDIT**
Let me put it this way. In normal php I could do something like this: 
    username;
    ?>

And then in view I could do something like:

```
 <?php 
        if (isset($_SESSION['username']))  
             {  
                echo '<input type="submit" name="Button" value="button"'; 
             }
 ?>
```

What is the equivalent in Phalcon?

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve your shared service via `DI::getShared('session')` (in your case in controller via `$this->session`) it will start the session for you, so no need to manually start it again. [Here](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/session.html#storing-retrieving-data-in-session) in documentation is pretty much how you should do it.

Another point, it would make the most sense to use [session bag](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/session.html#session-bags) or [persistent storage](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/session.html#persistent-data-in-components), second use the same implementation as session bags but kind of a shortcut.

And actually, not less of a valid point about retrieving session data in your views – you should pass it as a view variable, not implement that logic in the view (if you want more of a proper Phalcon way of doing stuff). I missed the part about `print_r($_SESSION)`. Can you actually `$this->view->setVar('myValue', 'my session value');` and see if that works in other views / controllers.

To set a value to your session bag in one place you do:

```
$users = Users::find(array($conditions, 'bind' => $parameters));
    if (count($users) > 0) {
        $user           = new Phalcon\Session\Bag('user');
        $user->username = $username;
    }
}
```

And then to retrieve it else where in another controller and pass it as a variable to view:

```
$user = new Phalcon\Session\Bag('user');
$this->view->setVar('userName', $user->username);
```

And then in the [volt view](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#basic-usage) to print it:

```
{% if username %}
    <input type="submit" name="Button" value="{{ username }}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: So if I set s value to a Session Bag can I gain access to it in for example the layout in order to show/hide some buttons? Or I would still have to excpliciltly pass it somehow to layout?

Comment: You certainly can, in other frameworks it's known as namespaces, in Phalcon it's session bags. Updated the answer to show how to retrieve the value.

Comment: That's great but does it mean that I have to pass session bag explicitly to every view?

Comment: You're missing a bigger picture. Session is your global object, you can access it any way you want anywhere you want, including how you described in the question. Session bag is just an interface, making it easier to work with the session. To a view you "normally" pass variables, e.g., username, not the whole session bag. I say "normally" because it's a good practice that not everyone follows, so in practice you can just pass a whole session bag, or instantiate it in the view if you really want that, or, again, just do `$_SESSION['user']['username']`.

Comment: Well, I know that the $_SESSION is a gloabal object, I am simply having an error when I try to for instance print_r($_SESSION) even though I am setting a variable through $this->persistent->username = $user->username;

Comment: I have already solved the problem. I wasn't setting the varibale from $user object to session. But than you for the responses anyway.Appreciate it